# Android ImageView @drawable options doesn't showed up

Tags: imageview, android-imageview, splash-screen, android-background, android-mipmap

android:src="@drawable/your_image" option doesn't show up but all the other .XML file options showed up. Even after I have copied the image in the drawable folder. "@mipmap/ic_launcher options showed up instead

Answer (score 1):

`sync` and `rebulid` the Android Studio again